# how to run several cmd command prompts from powershell

Tags: powershell, loops, batch-file, variables, cmd

So I am trying to write a script that allows  me to open several cmd command prompt and write in them the same command but with different variables.

The solution that I came with was to write a PowerShell script that calls inside a loop a cmd file and pass a variable each time to the cmd file but I'm stuck, the PowerShell script execute only one cmd.

Can someone help to figure this out ?

Thanks  :)

Comment: Show us your code :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following :

```
cmd.exe /c [command]
```

for example

```
$x = 1..100
foreach ($n in $x){cmd.exe /c ping 192.168.1.$n}
```

Comment: thank you for your response but your solution does not allow me to open a cmd prompt when i need to open a cmd first than execute some commands for my request

Answer (score 1):

[mohamed saeed's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71925031/45375) shows you to execute `cmd.exe` commands *synchronously, in sequence* in the *current console window*.

If, by contrast, you want to open multiple *interactive* `cmd.exe` sessions, *asynchronously*, each *in its separate, new window*, use `cmd.exe`'s `/k` option and invoke `cmd.exe` via [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process):

```sh
# Open three new interactive cmd.exe sessions in new windows 
# and execute a sample command  in each.
'date /t', 'ver', "echo $PSHOME" | ForEach-Object {
  # Parameters -FilePath and -ArgumentList implied.
  Start-Process cmd.exe /k, $_
}
```

Note:

- Unless your `cmd.exe` console windows have the `Let the system position the window` checkbox in the Properties dialog checked by default, all new windows will fully overlap, so that you'll immediately only see the last one opened.
- The last new window opened will have the keyboard focus.
- The commands passed to `/k` are *instantly* executed, but an interactive session is then entered.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to keep in purely batch, you can use the start command. The /k switch keeps the command line open. You would use /c if you want to carry out the command and terminate :

```
start "" %comspec% /k ping 192.168.1.1
```

From powershell, you can use the Start-Process command with an ArgumentList:

```
Start-Process cmd.exe -ArgumentList "/k ping 192.168.1.1"
```